# alpinjs Update store variable from outside

Tags: alpine.js

In alpinejs3 a store is set like:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('compare_tool', {
        items: { colors: [
            { id: 1, label: 'Red' },
            { id: 2, label: 'Orange' },
            { id: 3, label: 'Yellow' }
        ]},
        title: "my Title"
    })
})
```

Now an AJAX request from outside alpine should update `$store.compare_tool.items.colors`. I guess `$store` lives somewhere on the window object, but I cannot figure out how to get and set it.

Question: How can I update the store object from outside alpinejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [global `Alpine.store()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store#accessing%20stores) object that you can use for this:

```
Alpine.store('compare_tool').title = 'New title'
```

Comment: Thanks @Dauros would you say settings the items that way directly is good pracitce? Or should I better use a CustomEvent that I fire from outside and pass the ne data as event Detail?

Comment: If you need some kind of data validation, you can also define setter/getter methods inside the store object and mutate the data through them, e.g. `Alpine.store('compare_tool').update_items(new_items)`. For simple data structures it's fine to mutate the data directly. However If you have additional business logic that needs to be executed after you update the items, I think it's better to dispatch a custom event from the external JS with the item list as payload and update the store object from the respective Alpine.js component that listens for that specific custom event.